# How can I disable the message "Operating in maintenance mode. Go online." in maintenance mode?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal-7, maintenance-mode

I build site based on Drupal 7 and Twitter Bootstrap 3. Also, I output status messages into modal window.
But I use maintenance mode and for the each page a see the message "Operating in maintenance mode. Go online." and it should be close each time. So, it begins to annoy (please see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpSsM.png)).

How can I disable the message "Operating in maintenance mode. Go online." for the mode?

Thx for any answer.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`m so sorry, I founded the answer.
In template.php put next lines:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (variable_get('maintenance_mode', 0)) {
    $message_count = count($_SESSION['messages']['status']);
    if($message_count > 1) {
      array_shift($_SESSION['messages']['status']);
    }
    else {
      unset($_SESSION['messages']['status']);
    }
  }
}
```

Don`t forget change "mytheme" to name of your Drupal 7 theme.

Have a nice day!